The object placed in WebVR that is developed using A-Frame changes sometimes in VR mode
I developed a small office using A-Frame.
However, sometimes, or depending on the user, the space seems to shift to the left or right.
As a solution, I tried removing the look-controls or fixing the camera position, but it still moves.
It seems like the position of the space changes depending on the viewpoint. Is there any way to fix this?
I want to fix the VR environment.
        <a-entity id="rig">
            <a-entity id="camera" camera position="0 1.6 0" look-controls></a-entity>
            <a-entity id="left-hand" hand-tracking-controls="hand: left" hand-tracking-extras></a-entity>
            <a-entity id="right-hand" hand-tracking-controls="hand: right" hand-tracking-extras></a-entity>
        </a-entity>

        <!-- monitor --> 
        <a-entity gltf-model="#monitor" position="-0.406 1.7 -1.797" scale="3 3 2"></a-entity>
        <a-entity htmlembed position="-0.383 1.785 -1.692">
            <div class="scroll-box"></div>
        </a-entity>

Thank you for your interest in my question.
Best regards,
